# Server Map Path save problems when using IE or Safari

Tags: asp.net-mvc-4, format, httpcontext, save-as, server.mappath

I have created an intranet application and am having some difficulties with IE and safari on windows when trying to use the following code to save a posted file to an internal folder within the MVC solution folder structure:

```
postedFile.SaveAs(HttpContext.Current.Server.MapPath("~/" + baseFolderName + "/" + contentFolder + "/" + fileName));
```

This works as expected when using Firefox and chrome so I am unsure as to why this is happening something to do with the format of the string.

```
System.NotSupportedException: The given path's format is not supported.
```

The name of the basefolder and contentfolder being passed are the same in the tests so I am assuming the problem lies with IE trying to find the path.

Comment: You shoukd give extar info. Where do baseFolderName, and the other vars come from? Has you debugged and seen their values when you're using IE?

Comment: error was in the image.FileName path with IE as it was picking up full path which Chrome and Firefox seem to omit quite handily

Answer (score 3, accepted):

IE was getting the FileName of the posted file with its location included. I resolved the issue by getting just the file extension with the following code:

```
System.IO.Path.GetFileName(image.FileName))
```

Comment: is this the same case for safari?

Comment: I believe so @ViROscar